# Why the battery drain while plugged in doing nothing? (omap2_mcspi)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, usb, charging

I usually leave my phone plugged in to the wall charger at night.  This morning, to my surprise, the battery was not charged.  According to the System Panel app, System Processes were taking almost 10% of CPU during the entire night.  The biggest consumer was omap2_mcspi, taking nearly 15 minutes of CPU time, followed by khelper and cpcap_irq/0 both taking around 5 1/2 minutes, then ueventd and used at around 3 1/2 minutes, followed by battd at 3 minutes and vold at 2 1/2 minutes.

It seems pretty ridiculous to me that my battery would be running down while on the charger with the screen off and nothing (that should be) running.

Other than system processes, the only other thing taking any appreciable amount (around 1 minute) of CPU was "usb" which shows up outside of system processes.  My best guess is maybe the USB plug had some kind of issue, but I don't see any evidence of this (battery status updates don't show any apparent unplugging).

Comment: Could it be the plug was not connecting correctly? I have that quite often with my Optimus. After it happened for the first time (and I had to start the day with an almost empty battery), I always watch for the charging notification before turning the screen off; it that doesn't show, unplug and plug again. The usage values you report don't sound unreasonable, though I wonder a little about the [OMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omap) [SPI](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spi-summary) driver.

Comment: @Izzy that was my first thought, but I log battery readings and it shows charging status as expected.  I know what SPI is, but I don't know what peripherals it might be trying to talk to.

Comment: I thought *you* knew what OMAP and SPI are. But I also thought others might not (me included, concerning SPI), so the links wouldn't hurt :) As far as I understood, SPI could be used to access the SDCard, or other things *via USB*, so the latter might indicate some connection: could it have tried to "mount your charger" somehow -- due to some contact problem? Forgive me if that sounds stupid, but I'm not a dev and just rawly read the content behind above link ;)